# Server side data to client side. (Node.js + express)

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Good evening. We're just starting to implement server side code at school and it's confusing as hell. I have this piece of code on my client side .js that links to my server side .js. The server side contains an array of 2 objects. I'm trying to pull the length of the array through my client side. I've tried postsController.all.length and other things to no avail. Any clues?

```
var postsController = {

all: function() {
  $.get('/api/posts', function(data) {
    var allPosts = data;

    // iterate through allPosts
    _.each(allPosts, function(post) {
      // pass each post object through template and append to view
      var $postHtml = $(postsController.template(post));
      $('#post-list').append($postHtml);
    });
    // add event-handlers to phrases for updating/deleting
    postsController.addEventHandlers();
  });
},
```

Comment: For `postsController.all.length` to work, you would have to return the array from your `all` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not receiving JSON data from the server, instead jQuery is interpreting it as just text. I would recommend trying to use:

```
$.getJSON()
```

See more information here [on the jQuery documentation site](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: I got it to display the info that I needed on the page using $.getJSON( ). Thanks. I still can't pull the array length.

Comment: Could you update the question with the new code and maybe an example console.log so we can help you debug this?